# Is there any Quark extension or support for aws secret manager?

Tags: quarkus

We want migrate our java applications to Quarkus. We using AWS Secret Manager.
Is there any aws secret manager extension or solutions in Quarkus to read credentials from AWS Sectret manager.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't currently.

See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/main/extensions and https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/main/extensions/amazon-services for the list of Amazon related extensions